# StackOverflowException running SerializeObject

Tags: json.net

***I want to replicate the `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects` setting but have my own property name, rather than `$type`, and have it find the objects based on the simple class name rather than have the assembly referenced.***

I have a nested object model that I am trying to sterilise using the Newtonsoft tool. When I run it I get a `System.StackOverflowException` and I really cant figure out why... I have reviewed [Custom JsonConverter WriteJson Does Not Alter Serialization of Sub-properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267030/custom-jsonconverter-writejson-does-not-alter-serialization-of-sub-properties) and the solution there does not work natively within Newtonsoft and thus ignores all of the Newtonsoft native attributes.

If I pass a single convertor (all the object inherit from `IOptions`) I get only the top-level object with the required `ObjectType`:

```
{
  "ObjectType": "ProcessorOptionsA",
  "ReplayRevisions": true,
  "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
  "CollapseRevisions": false,
  "WorkItemCreateRetryLimit": 5,
  "Enabled": true,
  "Endpoints": null,
  "ProcessorEnrichers": [
    {
      "Enabled": true
    },
    {
      "Enabled": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I have 4 classes that all have my custom OptionsJsonConvertor set as the convertor.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(OptionsJsonConvertor<IProcessorEnricherOptions>))]
public interface IProcessorEnricherOptions : IEnricherOptions
{
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(OptionsJsonConvertor<IProcessorOptions>))]
public interface IProcessorOptions : IProcessorConfig, IOptions
{
    List<IEndpointOptions> Endpoints { get; set; }

    List<IProcessorEnricherOptions> ProcessorEnrichers { get; set; }

    IProcessorOptions GetDefault();
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(OptionsJsonConvertor<IEndpointOptions>))]
public interface IEndpointOptions : IOptions
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public EndpointDirection Direction { get; set; }

    public List<IEndpointEnricherOptions> EndpointEnrichers { get; set; }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(OptionsJsonConvertor<IEndpointEnricherOptions>))]
public interface IEndpointEnricherOptions : IEnricherOptions
{
}
```

The object model does not nest the same object type at any point, but does have `List<IEndpointEnricherOptions>` contained within `List<IEndpointOptions>` contained within `List<IProcessorOptions>`.

```
  "Processors": [
    {
      "ObjectType": "ProcessorOptionsA",
      "Enabled": true,
      "ProcessorEnrichers": [
        {
          "ObjectType": "ProcessorEnricherOptionsA",
          "Enabled": true
        },
        {
          "ObjectType": "ProcessorEnricherOptionsB",
          "Enabled": true,
        }
      ],
      "Endpoints": [
        {
          "ObjectType": "EndpointOptionsA",
          "EndpointEnrichers": [
            {
              "ObjectType": "EndpointEnricherOptionsA",
              "Enabled": true,
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "ObjectType": "EndpointOptionsA",
          "EndpointEnrichers": [
            {
              "ObjectType": "EndpointEnricherOptionsA",
              "Enabled": true,

            },
            {
              "ObjectType": "EndpointEnricherOptionsB",
              "Enabled": true,
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I want to replicate the `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects` setting but have my own property name as well as finding the objects, but everything else should be the same.

Right now I have `public class OptionsJsonConvertor<TOptions> : JsonConverter` which works for a single nested list, but no sub-lists.

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer,object value,JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    JToken jt = JToken.FromObject(value);
    if (jt.Type != JTokenType.Object)
    {
        jt.WriteTo(writer);
    }
    else
    {
        JObject o = (JObject)jt;
        o.AddFirst(new JProperty("ObjectType", value.GetType().Name));
        o.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

If I remove all of the `[JsonConverter]` class attributes then it executes and adds `ObjectType` to the `IProcessorOptions`, but not to any of the subtypes. However, with those attributes, I get `System.StackOverflowException` on  `JToken jt = JToken.FromObject(value);`

I had thought that this was due to it being the same object type, however even with 4 custom `JsonConverter` classes that don't share a common codebase I get the same exception.

**I'm stumped and really don't want to have the ugly `"$type" = "MyAssmbly.Namespace.Class, Assembly"` node!**

**UPDATE** Even if I only have the `OptionsJsonConvertor<IProcessorOptions>` enabled on the Class `IProcessorOptions` I get a `System.StackOverflowException`.

Comment: This basically looks to be the same problem as the one from [JSON.Net throws StackOverflowException when using `[JsonConvert()]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29719509/3744182).  Since your data structures are recursive, the "second, simpler workaround" from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29720068/3744182) should work for you.  (The first alternative from that answer will not work though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the resolution for this was somewhat of a compromise. We now have no customer `JsonConverter` types in the system and instead, use `ISerializationBinder`.

```
public class OptionsSerializationBinder : ISerializationBinder
{
    public void BindToName(Type serializedType, out string assemblyName, out string typeName)
    {
        assemblyName = null;
        typeName = serializedType.Name;
    }

    public Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        Type type = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
          .Where(a => !a.IsDynamic)
          .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
          .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name.Equals(typeName) || t.FullName.Equals(typeName));
        if (type is null || type.IsAbstract || type.IsInterface)
        {
            Log.Warning("Unable to load Processor: {typename}", typeName);
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        return type;
    }
}
```

Setting the `Assembly` option to `null` is critical to maintain the friendly names that we want.

```
    private static JsonSerializerSettings GetSerializerSettings(TypeNameHandling typeHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto)
    {
        return new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
            TypeNameHandling = typeHandling,
            TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling = TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.Simple,
            SerializationBinder = new OptionsSerializationBinder(),
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        };
    }
```

We can then set `SerializationBinder` and the default the `TypeNameHandling` to `auto`. We found when setting this to `Object` that it was too greedy and tried to write a `$type` for generic lists and such, creating a nasty look that did not serilise. `Auto` provided the right level for us.

If you need to use `Object` which will also apply to the root of your object map then you may need to create a customer wrapper class around any List<> or Dictionary<> object that you want to serialise to make sure it gets a friendly name.

Comment: For performance reasons in `BindToType()` I'd suggest caching the value returned by the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` query in a `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>`.